# Python Check if list of sets contains item

Tags: python, list, set

Suppose I have `L = [{'G'}, {'D'}, {'B','C'}]`.

I want to check if 'C' is in L.

I tried doing `{'C'} in L`, but it returns `False`.

How would I check if 'C' is in L?

Comment: {'B','C'} is in L, not exactly 'C'.

Comment: `any(['C' in s for s in L])` would do.

Comment: @ZdaR Why use a listcmp instead of a genexpr there? It's just wasting time and memory constructing a list when all you're going to do is pass it to `any` which will just call `iter` on it.

Answer (score 7):

You were matching a tuple with a string. What you have to do is -

1. Iterate the `list` of `set` using list comprehension
2. For each `set` check whether the search string exists
3. Take the `boolean` list of values and put it through `any()` function which returns `True` if any one of `boolean` items in the `list` is `True`.

You should do -

```
L = [{'G'}, {'D'}, {'B','C'}]
print(any([ 'C' in i for i in L]))
```

**Output**

```
True
```

For another example -

```
print(any([ 'X' in i for i in L]))
```

**Output**

```
False
```

Comment: Where is there a tuple? Has he edited the question since you answered it?

Comment: Thanks, I have another question if you don't mind. Its commented below

Answer (score 0):

You can also filter result basis on True False conditions :

```
L = [{'G'}, {'D'}, {'B','C'}]
word='C'

print([True if list(filter(lambda x:word in x,L)) else False])
```

output:

```
[True]
```

> **Update basis on comment:**

You can try this:

```
def union_similar(list_data,values_data):
    checker = {}
    final_ = []
    for item in list_data:
        for values in values_data:
            if values in item:
                if values not in checker:
                    checker[values] = [item]
                else:
                    checker[values].append(item)

    sub_ = set()
    for check, no in checker.items():

        if len(no) > 1:

            for i in no:
                sub_.update(*i)

                list_data.remove(i)
        else:
            sub_.update(*no[0])
            list_data.remove(no[0])

    list_data.append(sub_)
    return list_data

print(union_similar(L,c))
```

> output:

Test_case 1:

```
L = [{'G'}, {'D'}, {'B','C'}]
c=['C','G']
```

output:

```
[{'D'}, {'B', 'C', 'G'}]
```

Test_case_2:

```
L = [{'G'}, {'D'}, {'B','C'},{'U','C'}]
c=['C','G']
```

output:

```
[{'D'}, {'U', 'B', 'G', 'C'}]
```

Comment: ok thanks! Also how do I check if 'C' and 'G' are in different sets inside that list?

Comment: let c1 = 'C' and c2 = 'G'. I want to check that c1 and c2 are in different sets. If they are union them together so i get [{'G','B',C'},{'D'}]

Comment: So if they are in different set then union them , and if they are in same set then ?